# Why Default constructor need to declare in POJO file which has Parameterized Constructor while instantiating Object?

Tags: java, constructor, pojo, default-constructor

Suppose I have one POJO class User with a constuctor `public User(int id, String name){...}`. 
But when I instantiate the User object like `User u=new User()` with no parameter Eclipse gives error like **The constructor User() is undefined**. But it works fine when I have no parameterized Constructor. Can someone please explain why It requires to define default constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default (no-parameter) constructor is ONLY provided if you have provided no others. If you define even a single constructor for your class, you MUST use one of the explicitly defined (ie, in your code) constructors to instantiate the object. You can, of course, define your own zero-parameter, empty constructor if that works for what you're trying to do.

Edit:
Answer of `why?`

The compiler provides a default constructor so that the Object can be Instantiated when there are no constructors defined. But if you have defined a parametric constructor, it means that when you create a new instance of that class, its variables should initialized with the parameters you have passed(or do something similar). Without those initializations, the object might not behave in an expected way. Hence the compiler prevents such things from happening by not defining a default constructor(when you have defined one).

Comment: yeah I know that fact. But why so? Why JVM do not provide default constructor every time?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for "why". Because that's how the language was built. It's probably to avoid confusion in calling constructors that are nowhere explicitly defined. Java providing you with the default constructor is 100% a courtesy for your own convenience.

Comment: @VimalBera: It's not the JVM that provides a default constructor - it's the Java compiler.

Comment: _A child who does't know the way needs hand holding. But a person who knows where to go wouldn't need it._ If no constructor is defined compiler hand holds you. If you have a custom constructor, compiler interprets that you don't need a default no arg constructor. If you need one, you can explicitly define it.

Comment: Looks like the question became Jon Skeet vs JVM :)

Comment: @VimalBera, Its something like this:

The compiler provides a default constructor so that the Object can be Instantiated when there are no constructors defined. 


But if you have defined a parametric constructor, it means that when you create a new instance of that class, its variables should initialized with the parameters you have passed(or do something similar). Without those initializations, the object might not behave in an expected way. Hence the compiler prevents such things from happening by not defining a default constructor(when you have defined one).

Answer (score 2):

The no-arg constructor will be automatically added by the compiler if no constructor is provided by the developer. However, as soon as you put your own custom parameterized constructor, the compiler stops adding default constructor for you.

In this scenario, if you still want to use your no-arg constructor, you have to provide it yourself explicitly:

```
public User() {
}

public User(int id, String name) {
}
```

The logic behind this is that: if you define your own parametrized constructor, you are declaring that the parameters listed in the constructor is required to construct an object of the class. Therefore you are also implicitly declares if the user of your library do not provide these two parameters, the object shouldn't be able to construct. Thus the compiler will not add the no-arg constructor for you.

If you want to also declare that your class can still work if none of the specified parameters in the parametrized constructor is provided and you (no arg), then you have the explicitly declare that by providing the non-arg constructor yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving answer so late, but let's try to share with you what i know:

1. When you don't provide constructor compiler provides constructor. Why ? Because it is sure you are going to initialize your object with no argument constructor only. So compiler does it for you.
2. When you provide parameterised constructor, then compiler doesn't know which constructor you will use to initialize your object. So compiler does not provide for you one no-argument constructor. So you have to write explicitly.

   Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you have. :)

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler automatically provides a no-parameter, default constructor for any class without constructors. If there is no constructor defined in your class then Java compiler will add a no parameter constructor in your generated class file. But if there is a constructor with parameter in your class, then you need to write the no-parameter constructor, compiler will not add it.

Comment: You keep talking about the JVM adding the constructor - it doesn't. The compiler does. (And it's a constructor without *parameters*, not *arguments* - arguments are supplied when *calling* a constructor or method.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yep i was correcting it while you were commmenting :-) Thanks!

Comment: But not the arguments part? (I'm not sure this answer actually adds anything over Kon's anyway, to be honest.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, while I agree on the general usage of terms that arguments are passed and parameters are received; using the term *default no-arg constructor* is quite common.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Common, and incorrect. Why propagate that incorrectness? There are lots of poor uses of terminology - I'm trying to improve the use of terminology, as I view it as important.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors but if you explicitly provide any constructor with arguments then compiler will not provide a default constructor mainly due to security reasons.

So what you can do is

```
 public User(int id, String name){...}
 public User(){this(defualtID,defaultName)};
```